# Laravel 5 reset password form not submitting if password is less than 6 characters

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am trying to reset my password but not able rest password if password length is less then `6`. I am validating password filed with `min:4` validation but when I enter more then 4 character form is not submitting but when I tried with more then 6 it is working.

Any Idea what is wrong in my code.

### Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="reset_password_container">
    <div class="reset_bg">
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/password/reset') }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ $token }}">

            <div class="find_account_container">
                <div class="find_inner_logo">
                    <h5>{{ trans('messages.reset_password_form.reset_password') }}</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="find_form_dv">
                    <div class="reset_para_dv">
                        <p>{{ trans('messages.reset_password_form.text_1') }}</p>
                        <div class="reset_email_dv">
                            <p>{{ trans('messages.reset_password_form.email') }} <a href="javascript:void(0);">{{ $email }}</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="reset_form_dv">
                        <input type="hidden" class="txt" name="ID" value="{{ $email }}">
                        <input type="password" class="txt" name="password" value="{{ old('password') }}" placeholder="{{ trans('messages.reset_password_form.password') }}">
                        <p class="error"></p>

                        <input type="password" class="txt" name="password_confirmation" value="{{ old('password_confirmation') }}" placeholder="{{ trans('messages.reset_password_form.password_confirmation') }}">
                        <p class="error">
                            @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                {{ $errors->first('password') }}
                            @endif
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="reset_footer_bg">
                <div class="rest_btn_bg">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{{ trans('messages.reset_password_form.confirm') }}</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

### PasswordController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Mail\Message;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Mail;
use DB;


class PasswordController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reset Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling password reset requests
    | and uses a simple trait to include this behavior. You're free to
    | explore this trait and override any methods you wish to tweak.
    |
    */

    use ResetsPasswords;

    /**
     * Create a new password controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //$this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get the post register / login redirect path.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function redirectPath()
    {
        if (property_exists($this, 'redirectPath')) {
            return $this->redirectPath;
        }

        return property_exists($this, 'redirectTo') ? $this->redirectTo : '/dashboard';
    }

    /**
     * Display the password reset view for the given token.
     *
     * @param  string  $token
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function getReset($token = null, Request $request)
    {
        if (is_null($token)) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException;
        } else {
            $userReset = DB::table('password_resets')->select('email')->where('token','=',$token)->get();
        }

        if (!empty($userReset)) {
            return view('auth.reset')->with('token', $token)->with('email', $userReset[0]->email);
        } else {
            return redirect('/');
        }

    }

    /**
     * Send a reset link to the given user.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function postEmail(Request $request)
    {
        //Input::get('ID') die;
        $this->validate($request, ['ID' => 'required|email']);

        // Pass data to reset password mail template
        view()->composer('emails.password', function($view) {
            $view->with([
                'Nickname'   => Input::get('nickname'),
            ]);
        });

        $response = Password::sendResetLink($request->only('ID'), function (Message $message) {
            $message->subject('비밀번호 재설정 안내');
            //$message->subject($this->getEmailSubject());
        });

        if ($response == "passwords.sent") {
            $html = '<div class="img_left_dv"><img src="resources/assets/front/images/suggestion_2.png" alt=""/></div>
            <div class="text_right_dv">
                <h3>'.Input::get('nickname').'</h3>
                <p><a href="javascript:void(0);">'.Input::get('ID').'</a> '.trans('messages.reset_password_popup.confirmation_message').'</p>
            </div>';
            echo $html;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reset the given user's password.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function postReset(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'token' => 'required',
            'ID' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|min:4|confirmed',
            'password_confirmation' => 'required|same:password|min:4'
        ]);

        $credentials = $request->only(
            'ID', 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'token'
        );

        $response = Password::reset($credentials, function ($user, $password) {
            $this->resetPassword($user, $password);
        });

        switch ($response) {
            case Password::PASSWORD_RESET:
                return redirect($this->redirectPath())->with('status', trans($response));

            default:
                return redirect()->back()
                            ->withInput($request->only('ID'))
                            ->withErrors(['ID' => trans($response)]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you extend classes to get this reset password functionality to work. Possibly an extra validation is going off, before your own validation goes off. My guess would be, that in the original code these 6 characters are required. Maybe this file has to do something with it? /Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php

Answer (score 1):

Please try below function:

By default, the Password::reset method will verify that the passwords match and are >= six characters. You may customize these rules using the Password::validator method, which accepts a Closure. Within this Closure, you may do any password validation you wish. Note that you are not required to verify that the passwords match, as this will be done automatically by the framework.

```
Password::validator(function($credentials)
{
    return strlen($credentials['password']) >= 4;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your validation rule in `postReset` is superseded by `getResetValidationRules` function in `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords.php`:

```
protected function getResetValidationRules()
{
    return [
        'token' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ];
}
```

To fix this, you need to:

- Add the `getResetValidationRules` function to your `PasswordController.php` file.
- Remove the `postReset` function you created (this is just duplicating code that already exists)
- Rename your `ID` form field to `email` and let Laravel handle the rest

So, you `PasswordController.php` should just contain:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;

class PasswordController extends Controller
{

    use ResetsPasswords;

    /**
     * Create a new password controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    public function getResetValidationRules()
    {
        return [
            'token' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:4',
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. I have updated my question and added my full controller. I am using ID as email.

Comment: Have you even tried my solution? If you rename ```ID``` to ```email```, Laravel handles a lot of the functionality for you. But if you still want to use ```ID```, just update the rule in my ```getResetValidationRules``` function. This is a working and valid solution At least give it a go to see if it resolves your issue.

Comment: I have tried `public function getResetValidationRules()
    {
        return [
            'token' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:4',
        ];
    }` code but still not getting. Everything is working perfect If password length is grater five.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same issue in Laravel 5.2. The reset password form requires a password of six or more characters, and it is set that way in two places.

**1. PasswordBroker Class**
`vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/PasswordBroker.php:validatePasswordWithDefaults()`

```
    protected function validatePasswordWithDefaults(array $credentials)                                                      
{   
    list($password, $confirm) = [
        $credentials['password'],
        $credentials['password_confirmation'],
    ];

    return $password === $confirm && mb_strlen($password) >= 6;
}
```

and

**2. ResetsPasswords Trait**
`vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/ResetsPasswords.php:getResetValidationRules()`

```
    protected function getResetValidationRules()
{   
    return [
        'token' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ];  
}
```

It is easy to override the `getResetValidationRules()` trait method in your `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/PasswordController.php` by implementing your own `reset()` and `getResetValidationRules()` methods.

However, in order to call your own `PasswordBroker.php:validatePasswordWithDefaults()` method it looks like it would require extending the PasswordBroker and PasswordBrokerManager and since that is initialized by the `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/PasswordResetServiceProvider.php` you will need to extend that as well. When all is done you can initialize your new "`CustomPasswordResetServiceProvider`" in Laravel's service container just as `ResetPasswordServiceProvider` is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [gist](https://gist.github.com/jamesfairhurst/a30f034f6aeef45fe32f17e5588c1adf) to solve the issue. You have to create a new service provider which uses your custom password broker manager. When every thing is set up all you have to do is add your new service provider to your config\app.php :

```
'providers' => [
     ...
     // path to your PasswordResetServiceProvider
     App\Auth\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class 
 ]
```